# How to use subprocess run with cat << EOF > in python

Tags: python

I have the following shell

```
cat << EOF > ~/.aws/config
[profile default]
key=value
EOF
```

I tried the following in python

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['cat', '<< EOF >','~/.aws/config','\n[profile default]\nkey=value\nEOF'])
```

This was not specified correctly, but it is not obvious to me how this should be specified.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use `shell=True` to process this.

```
subprocess.run("""cat <<EOF > ~/.aws/config
[profile default]
key=value
EOF
""", shell=True)
```

but there's little reason to invoke a shell (or any other subprocess) just to write to a file.

```
with open(pathlib.Path.home() / ".aws/config", "w") as f:
    f.write("[profile default]\nkey=value\n")
```